# recover a projection matrix with known 3d and 2d points

Tags: opencv, math, matrix, 3d, projection

Given known 3D to 2D point correspondences, how can we recover a projection matrix

I was wondering if there was a way to find the projection matrix of a camera using a human drawn 3d plane. So basically the plane should already be projected because the user inputs the points of the plane. The x, y and z coordinates of the plane is known. All that needs to happen is work out what the projection matrix is given the 2d points on the screen as well as the 3d points that is not visible to the user.

The camera is pointed at a set angle to allow for depth.
See example of the drawn plane:

[image]

I know its a bit skew, but the image i uploaded is a bit out of date. my latest method does a way better job, on the new method im able to create a projected cube.

[image]

Would it be possible to get the projection matrix from this if all points are known?

Comment: solvePnP........

Comment: Thank you, I did not know about this. But now I still have to get the camera matrix from the square. If I can get the camera matrix I can do the solve PNP myself. Is there a way I can get it from the square?

Comment: So i found this answer in regards to my previous comment : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8824126/opencv-resolvepnp-without-camera-and-distortion-matrices. this calculates the camera matrix using the fov. Would it be possible to get the fov of the camera using the length of one of the sides of the squere as well as the distance to the camera?